# javascript - array with key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to have a key value pair in arrays in javascript. I'm looking to have something like the following

```
const array = 
[
'item': 'Jumper', 'price', '160',
'item': 'Shirt', 'price', '50',
'item': 'Cap', 'price', '20',
]
```

Or is there a better datastructure to use?

Comment: What's the point of having *key/value pairs* where all the keys are same?

Comment: If you need key-value pairs, you've to use object. In your case it looks like you'd need an array of objects.

Comment: "Better" is hard to determine unless you provide context on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you need O(1) price lookups or are you looking to store a collection primarily for iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just make it an array of objects:

```js
const array = 
[
{'item': 'Jumper', 'price': '160'},
{'item': 'Shirt', 'price': '50'},
{'item': 'Cap', 'price': '20'},
]

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Good but also consider `products = {Jumper: 160, Shirt: 50, Cap: 20}` depending on use case; this gives O(1) lookup of price given a name. It's unusual to have numbers represented as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use objects. You can do it the way it's shown in @dave's answer, or you can instead use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Product {
    constructor(item, price) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

const array = [
    new Product('Jumper', 160),
    new Product('Shirt', 50),
    new Product('Cap', 20),
];
```